# Store Previous row value for current row in Crystal Report

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I want to retrieve previous row value in current row just like below (Crystal Report 2008):

```
+------------+-----------------+----------+------------+----------------+
| Date       | PreviousBalance | Loan     | Collection | CurrentBalance |
+============+=================+==========+============+================|
| 14/02/2012 | 00.00           | 10000.00 | 00.00      | 10,000.00      |
| 15/02/2012 | 10,000.00       | 00.00    | 500.00     | 9,500.00       |
| 16/02/2012 | 9,500.00        | 00.00    | 500.00     | 9,000.00       |
| 18/02/2012 | 9,000.00        | 5,000.00 | 00.00      | 14,000.00      |
+------------+-----------------+----------+------------+----------------+
```

Comment: where does in given example... previous row balance is used in current row?

Comment: Can you explain more precisely?

Answer (score 3):

It's easier than it seems:

1. Create two Running Totals one for Loan `{#TLoan}` for the field `{table.Loan}` and one for Collection `{#TCol}` for the field `{table.Collection}`.
2. Create a Formula: `{@Total}` with following content:

`{#TLoan}-{#TCol}`

**This will have CurrentBalance value.**

3. Create another formula: `{@Prev}` with following content:

`{@Total}-{table.Loan}+{table.Collection}`

**This will have PreviousBalance value.**

Using this approach don't need complicated formulas and the result is the expected.

[image]

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: Don't worry! if it helps it worth!

Answer (score 2):

The use of the `previous()` function seems like it would be the obvious choice for this solution, but because formulas can't reference each other cyclically (that is, `{@CurrentBalance}` can't reference `{@PreviousBalance}` and vice-versa) nor can they be recursive it's tougher to implement it this way than it first seems.

Instead, you should use a variable to keep track of the balance between transactions. You can accomplish this by creating 3 formulas and placing them in the appropriate sections of your report.

```
// {@initVars} - Initialize balance variable
//This formula should be placed in your report header
whileprintingrecords;
numbervar balance:=0

// {@previousBalance} - Display previous line's balance
//This formula should be placed in your Details section
whileprintingrecords;
numbervar balance;

// {@currentBalance} - Display current balance after transactions
//This formula should be placed in your Details section
evaluateafter({@previousBalance});
numbervar balance := balance + {table.LoanAmount} - {table.CollectionAmount}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there are a number of ways. How about:

`previous({Table.Field})`

Or you could have a running total then do `{#total} - {Table.Field}`?

Comment: what is previous({Table.Field}) is empty? how to set it to a value?

Answer (score 1):

In the stored procedure store the previous balance inside variable by using function that reads from the table and returns the previous balance and store it inside a variable then inside the Stored Procedure read the current balance.
Use **union** to read previous and Current in separated rows and get them in the report.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
// {@PreviousBalance}
If PreviousIsNull({@CurrentBalance}) Then
  0
Else
  Previous({@CurrentBalance})
```

Answer (score 0):

from the stored procedure (if you are using one) order the data by date ASC, or if you are not using SP you hane to sort the data table or data set by date ASC, then you have to determine GROUPING criteria (ClientId) to group the information for one client for example in such ordering and grouping as you mentioned, you can group the records from (Field Explorer -> Group Name Fields -> Insert Group)

Comment: as i understand from the question it is some sort of financial or banking system so there will be an identity column for example (ClientID) it can be used to for grouping

Answer (score 0):

please look at this [link](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/09/22/sql-server-how-to-access-the-previous-row-and-next-row-value-in-select-statement/). You haven't specified the underlying datasource so I found a sample for MS SQL.

If you do not have access to the database in order to query / edit stored procedure, you can write a foreach loop and calculate the appropriate values. The problem is that reports usually summarize, slice and filter data. The concept of "previous" and "following" loses it's meaning in that context.